# PyQt5 QSpinBox Locking/Unlocking in Context Menu

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside2

I've added a locking checkbox in a spinbox's context menu that disables the spinbox using `self.setDisabled(True)`. Is there any way I can open the context menu while the spinbox is disabled, to access the locking checkbox ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling a widget also makes it unresponsive to mouse and keyboard events, which obviously also prevents showing the context menu.

Instead of disabling it, use the [readOnly](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractspinbox.html#readOnly-prop) property:

```
def setSpinEnabled(self, enabled):
    self.mySpecialSpin.setReadOnly(not enabled)
```